# Invertir la fecha de DD/MM/YYYY a YYYY/MM/DD

Tags: javascript

Quizás mi pregunta es super tonta, pero quisiera saber como hacer esto, tengo un *datepicker* llamado `fecha_nacimiento` que al mostrarlo en mi consola me llega así **`29/05/1991`**.

```
var fecha_nac = $("#fecha_nacimiento").val();
console.log(fecha_nac);
console.log(convertFech(fecha_nac));  //esto me trae el formato requerido
```

Cree esta función:

```
function convertFech(string) {
    var fech = string.split('/');
    return fech[2] + '-' + fech[1] + '-' + fech[0];
}
```

Pero necesito dar vuelta la fecha y que me llegue **`1991/05/29`**, ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: No es mejor configurar el datepicker con ese formato?

Comment: Y eso como seria? porque estoy aprendido dia a dia de esto

Comment: Primero, muestranos como le asignas el datepicker a `fecha_nacimiento`

Comment: $('.daterange-single').daterangepicker({
                singleDatePicker: true,
                locale: {
                    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
                    startDate: '-4d',
                    daysOfWeek: ["Dom","Lun","Mar","Mie","Jue","Vie","Sáb",],
                    monthNames: ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"
                    ],
                    firstDay: 1
                }
            });

Comment: Lo cambie a como me dijiste y funcionó

Comment: Tengo otra consulta, si presiono mi daterangepicker y va a buscar un una consulta a traves de un json, como es posible que logre cerrar el daterangepicker y no se me mantenga abierto?, agregue autoclose: true, pero no hace nada

Comment: Perfecto!. Sobre lo otro, tendrias que crear una nueva pregunta poniendo que usas [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) y no [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: @JuanRivera, eso como seria, porque ahí me perdi

Comment: De tu consulta "*si presiono mi daterangepicker y va a buscar...*" deberias crear una nueva pregunta, ya que en esta hablas de "*Invertir la fecha de DD/MM/YYYY a YYYY/MM/DD*"

Comment: Ok, amigo, ahora entendí, mil gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacer:

```js
let fecha_nac = "29/05/1991"
const [dia, mes, ano] = fecha_nac.split("/");
let cambiada = `${ano}/${mes}/${dia}`;

console.log(cambiada)
```

O también puedes hacerlo así en una sola línea

```js
 let fecha_nac = "29/05/1991"
 const cambiada = fecha_nac.split("/").reverse().join("/");
console.log(cambiada)
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, igual lo había resuelto, actualizaré mi código para ver si estoy bien con lo que hice

Comment: Aunque en el código actual usas `-` como separador... y en la pregunta nombraste que el formato que querías era `1991/05/29`... si te sirve con `-` lo que hiciste está bien también

Comment: Muchas gracias...